# ConvertTimeToUtc culture

Tags: c#, datetime-format, culture

Right now this string is returning: "Giovedi 24 Ottobre 2013", which is absolutely correct.
I have adjust the result with a +1 hour for my specific needs.
I need the string to return "Thursday 24 October 2013", basically the same but in English.

```
 private string Datetime()

{
    DateTime dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now);

    return dt.AddHours(1).ToLongDateString();
}
```

How can I change the method to return the date in English?

Comment: Also you can probably just use `DateTime.UtcNow`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to use the `TimeZoneInfo` class to do this...

```
return DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Comment: this solved my problem. Thanks a lot. I used  return dt.AddHours(1).ToString("D", new CultureInfo("en-US"));

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
return dt.AddHours(1).ToString("D", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I suspect your string will not return UTC but the system time. Am I wrong? I need the UTC time.

Comment: Was a polite answer. Your string returns the system time and not the UTC. I need to apply culture en-EN to ConvertTimeToUtc. Thats my problem. However, thanks.

Comment: Snippet will return **date in `dt`** in format "Long date pattern" and in culture `en-US`.

Comment: Thanks, I know but I was looking for culture on UTC time.

Comment: Your dt already in UTC `DateTime dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now);`